# Azure Service bus queues topics vs queues for web/worker roles

Tags: service, azure, bus

I know 
[Choosing between .NET Service Bus Queues vs Azure Queue Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906244/choosing-between-net-service-bus-queues-vs-azure-queue-service)

provides some answers as to when to use queues for web/worker roles vs Azure Service bus, but I'm just starting to study Azure and was looking for something more thorough.

It says "NET service bus is more specifically designed for integrating systems rather than providing a general purpose reliable messaging system".

Was just wondering if I could get clarification of this? Does it mean when communicating between separate remote applications it is better to use the Service bus Queue and when communicating between web/worker roles you use the normal Azure queues.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The service bus queues offer a lot more sophistication compared to the storage queue counterpart. 
Here is a link comparing and contrasting.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted

I would use the queue which best serve my needs favoring storage queue for generic work distribution and the service bus queues, if my needs are more sophisticated like Pub/Sub etc ...

Answer (score 5):

The service bus queues & topics follows AMQP, which includes FIFO queues, pub/sub, acknowledge modes, etc. It's more standard and open, which means if you want to integrate your system with other application without any effort if it also follows AMQP.

The storage queue is more simple than the service bus one. It gives us an asynchronously channel between the roles. The communication protocol, message structure and format are all based on ourselves.

HTH

Comment: What is AMQP? If I use the service bus queue for my web/worker roles can I still access the storage?

Comment: AMQP, please refer http://www.amqp.org/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol. The service bus queue and storage are totally separated. You can access your storage regardless if you are using service bus queue or not.